# If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ why are 1 of 3 conditions necessary? (see question for details)

Tags: general-topology

If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ (we are not told whether A is open or closed) and $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$, and there is an open rectangle $B$ such that $x \in B \subset (\mathbb{R}^N-A)$, what guarantee is there that $\mathbb{R}^N-A$ is an open set so that if the above condition holds, then that implies that $x$ is not on the set of points that form a "boundary" between $A$ and $B$?

> EDIT: further clarification

In Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, he explains the following: if $A \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$, then one of three conditions must hold: 1) there is an open rectangle $B$ such that $x \in B \subset A$, 2) there is an open rectangle $B$ such that $x \in B \subset \mathbb{R}^N-A$ or 3) if $B$ is any open rectangle, and $x \in B$ then $B$ contains points of both $A$ and $\mathbb{R}^N-A$.

Is the third condition necessary only because we do not know whether A is open or not? Thus, if A is open, then condition 1 and 2 will fail, and we require condition 3), but if A is closed, then condition 1 and 3 will succeed, while condition 2 will fail?

Comment: It's a general statement, and often the definition, that $\mathbb{R^n} - A$ is open precisely when $A$ is closed.  Besides that, I'm having a hard time deciphering your question.

Comment: Ok.  So I think your question is:  Why is it true that if for some $x \in R^N$  where there exists an open rectangle $B$ such that $x \in B \subset R^N - A$ then $x$ is _not_ in the boundary of $A$ (or $B$). ??

Comment: @breedeen In Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, he explains the following: if $A \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$, then one of three conditions must hold: 1) there is an open rectangle $B$ such that $x \in B \subset A$, 2) there is an open rectangle $B$ such that $x \in B \subset \mathbb{R}^N-A$ or 3) if $B$ is any open rectangle, and $x \in B$ then $B$ contains points of both $A$ and $\mathbb{R}^N-A$. Is the third condition necessary only because we do not know whether A is open or not?

Comment: The last condition is simply the negation of the first two. If neither 1) nor 2) hold, then 3) must hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have been able to answer my own question. I was thinking that condition 3) was only necessary if $A$ is open, as I mistakenly thought that condition 1) would capture $x$ if $A$ was closed, but that's not the case. Even if $A$ was closed, condition 1) would not be able to capture $x$ if $x$ was on the boundary of $A$, since $x$ has to be in an open rectangle $B \subset A$ (i.e. $B$ cannot contain the boundary points of $A$ while maintaining the condition that it is a subset of $A$ and an open set). Therefore, condition 3) is necessary regardless of whether $A$ is open or closed.

Comment: To be precise, all three cases may occur (by varying $x$) for open $A$, all three cases mya occur for closed $A$ and all three cases may occur for neither-open-nor-closed $A$. But your findings are correct: (1) is equivalent to "$x$ is an *interior* point of $A$"; (2) is equivalent to "$x$ is an *exterior* point fo $A$"; (3) is equivalent to "$x$ is a *boundary* point of $A$". - To repeat, all three kinds of points may (or may not) exist for all kinds of $A$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}^N-A$ is closed iff $A$ is open.  We can always find $B\subset \mathbb{R}^N-A$ regardless if $A$ is open or closed or $B$ is desired to be open or closed.

To be more explicit...  Because $\mathbb{R}^N-A$ is open/closed there exists an open/closed ball contained in it of some radius, $r\in \mathbb{R}$.  From this we can derive an infinite sequence of nonempty closed and open balls (sets), of radius $\frac{r}{2},\frac{r}{3},\cdots$

Comment: Sure.. you can take $B = \emptyset$.  But that's about your only guarantee.

Comment: @Squirtle Hi, I have added some further clarification to my question.

Comment: which chapter and question number of spivak is it... I'll read it there and get back to you

Comment: @Squirtle It's in Chapter 1, page 6. I think I get it now though. I was thinking that condition 3) was only necessary if $A$ is open, but that's not the case. Even if $A$ was closed, condition 1) would not be able to capture $x$ if x was on the boundary of $A$, since $x$ has to be in an open rectangle $B \subset A$ (i.e. $B$ cannot contain the boundary points of $A$ while maintaining the condition that it is a subset of $A$ and an open set).